# Does std::function keeps a reference to captured variables

Tags: c++

I'd like to understand why the following works:

```
class Foo {
public:
    using Callback = std::function<void(std::string& string)>;

    void setCallback(Callback&& callback) { windowInfo = callback; };
private:
    Callback windowInfo;
};

class Bar {
    Bar() { foo->setCallback([this](std::string& e) { sayHello(e); });}
    void sayHello(std::string& name) { //do something }

    Foo* foo;
};
```

`Foo::setCallback` asks for a function with no captures, however, I'm passing a lambda that captures `Bar`. I would expect the compiler to complain `void(Bar, string)` != `void(string)`. Since I'm passing in a **member** function, it must implicitly pass the $this parameter as the first argument. Making the function signatures not equivalent.

**EDIT**

Why is that when I redefine `using EventCallback` as `using EventCallback = void(Event& event);` suddently this doesn't work anymore "no viable conversion from `Application.cpp:10:34` to `Foo::Callback aka (...)`

Is `std::function` acting as the "glue" holding a reference to `Bar` but exposing the correct signature when requested?

Comment: "*Foo::setCallback asks for a function with no captures*" No, it asks for any object callable with that signature. That's what `std::function` *does*. "*Since I'm passing in a member function*" Where? I see no code where you're getting a pointer to a member.

Comment: Not the answer, but `setCallback` should probably be rewritten as `void setCallback(Callback callback) {windowInfo = std::move(callback);};`.

Comment: Even if you don't change the signature, you should still use `windowInfo = std::move(callback);` as rvalue references aren't rvalues.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I updated my question. I think I'm having trouble understanding what's the difference between lambdas and std::functions

Comment: Would it be right to think of "lambdas" as "classes" where the captures are the data members, and with an `operator()(xxx)` overload, where xxx in my case is 'Event'.  Is std::function some kind of "boxed" lambda?